# docker compose exec -T not working in cron

Tags: docker

I have a crontab to execute daily DB backups. The DB is part of a docker compose so I run this command in my cron script:

```bash
cd /home/ubuntu/my_project/ \
  && /usr/bin/docker compose exec -T db pg_dump -U postgres > $BACKUP_FILE
```

This command fails with `unknown shorthand flag : 'T' in -T`, even though it runs completely fine from my terminal.

I have specified the path to docker as other SO answers have suggested, but I don't understand why docker is complaining when executed from cron.
Also all other resources I find on the internet is using `docker-compose` not `docker compose` so I am not getting help from there either.

I have also confirmed that the PATH variable from cron is the same as my normal terminal.

```
* * * * * echo $PATH > tmp.txt 2&>1
```

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: `docker-compose` was previously a separate command, it was migrated to a subcommand of `docker` (`docker compose` with no hyphen) last year. Does it work if you just redirect stdout/err? I've also seen a few bug reports over on the compose and CLI repos about flag order causing issues, so it might be worth filing a new issue over there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I changed the 2nd line command to `/usr/bin/docker compose exec -T db pg_dump -U postgres`, so cron outputs to specified log file, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant redirecting _instead_ of using the `-T` flag.  Trying the long version (`--no-TTY`) might also be worth a shot (though from looking over the flag-parsing code, it'll probably also fail with `unknown flag:`).

Comment: Thank you! After removing the `-T` to use `xxx`, I got this error `unknown shorthand flag: 'U' in -U`. It seems like `docker compose` is not interpreting my command correctly, but I have not been able to find other people with the same issue

Comment: Well, I'm a little confused! I'm assuming this is already in a separate script, and not directly in your crontab? And `/usr/bin/docker` is the same (or at least the same version) as what you get with `which docker` in the shell?

Comment: Yes, they are in a separate script with `#!/bin/bash` at the start, and `which docker` is the same output both on my shell and from cron

Comment: Does your database container have published `ports:`?  Can you directly run `pg_dump` from the host, without running any `docker` commands?

Answer (score 0):

While I was not able to understand the root cause of this, the quickest fix for my problem was to

- install `docker-compose`, and
- repace `docker compose` commands with `docker-compose`.

After this I was able to run the script from cron without any other changes.

I am suspecting that this is due to `docker compose` being a newer feature, as pointed out by Zac, but I have not done any further investigation on this.

Comment: Normally I give the suggestion to bind a simple shell script within cron so that the details of invoking a specific command (e.g. controlling the working directory, specifying the concrete command etc.) is less bound to the change in the cron table itself. It can also make the entry in the crontab more speaking. Just FYI. /E: and trouble-shooting: execute under the cron user and see what happens similar to what happens while the cron daemon invokes it.